How to map a 2d (multidimensional) array in Hibernate 6.5 using JPA?
I am using the latest hibernate version (6.5) and hypersistence utils in this version is not supporting custom array types as it's natively supported by hibernate > 6.4.
I've tested and this works natively for float[] arrays, so e.g. this works
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    float[] myArray
}

but if I do the same for a 2d array:
float[][] myArray

I get this error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
class org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType (org.hibernate.type.internal.BasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
So it seems mapping the column as json and using columnDefinition = "jsonb" seems to be only solution. Is there another way to map multidimensional arrays natively supported by hibernate 6.5?

Hypersistence-Utils and PostgreSQL support the use of multi-dimensional arrays.
@Type(value = FloatArrayType.class)
@Column(name = "data", columnDefinition = "real[][]")
private float[][] data;

Tested using
org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.5.3.Final
io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63:3.8.3


I get this when I try it:
Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [confusion_matrix] in table [scores]; found [_float8 (Types#ARRAY)], but expecting [float8[][] (Types#OTHER)]
and here's my mapping (I'm using Kotlin):
    @Type(value = FloatArrayType::class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "float8[][]")
    val multiClassConfusionMatrix: Array<FloatArray>?


@AlexArvanitidis Just turn off validation.

Consider using a custom type definition using the built-in FloatPrimitiveArrayJavaType
@Type(value = FloatPrimitiveArrayJavaType.class, parameters = @Parameter(name = "sql_array_type", value = "float_array"))
@Column(name = "2d_float_array", columnDefinition = "float_array[][]")
private float[][] myArray;

